# Angular4 to parse, process and modify HTML content

Tags: angular

I am building a publishing app with Angular4. It is fine until I am requested to implement a function that can **read existing HTML content, parse and modify it**.

For example, given a HTML input string

```
I am a <span class="color-red">Angular</span> <b>newbie</b>.
<div class="premium-photo">
    <img src="/upload/old-photo.jpg">
</div>
Other HTML...
```

I want to identify all the `div` with the class `premium-photo` and read the `img.src` in the container, and change the `img.src` content and re-publish the article again.

The process output string should be: (note that `img.src` has been changed, while leaving other HTML untouched).

```
I am a <span class="color-red">Angular</span> <b>newbie</b>.
<div class="premium-photo">
    <img src="/new-upload/new-and-more-beautiful-photo.jpg">
</div>
Other HTML...
```

Can I use Angular4 to implement this function? I used Angular for MVC app front-end interface, but not sure how to implement this function in Angular.

Any suggestion? Do I need to use jQuery `$('div.premium-photo').find('img').attr('src')` approach?

Please advice. Any fastest approach?